# Ubuntu-One password and safety

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm on 11.10 using auto login. So the "unlock default keyring" prompt on startup kept bothering me. I read about the solutions. At "Passwords and keys" I was only able to delete the Ubuntu-One PW, which I thought was responsible for the prompt. I saved it before deleting it. It was the only PW shown there. It wasn't the one I had to enter once to access my account though. I did a reboot but the "unlock..." prompt still pops up. But I can't put the PW back where it was because the Ubuntu One entry is gone. Now I can't connect to Ubuntu-One anymore. It says "There was a problem while retrieving the credential". What can I do about this? And how can I get rid of the "unlock..." prompt without my system getting unsafe?

Comment: Could enter PW again after a reboot. Ubuntu One works again now. But I'm still not happy with deleting my keyring PW. Is there an alternative? Is this bug gonna be fixed with the next release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. If we don't store your credentials somewhere, then we would have to ask you for your Ubuntu One password on every login.

If we store the credentials in a safe place, like we do now with the Keyring, then the Keyring will ask you for its password when you login.

The only "solutions" for this are:

1) You make the keyring less secure and it doesn't ask for a password on login.
2) Ubuntu One stores the credentials insecurely (outside of the keyring) like some other
   applications do.

Both are a security risk, since anyone with physical access to your device can grab your credentials.

In my opinion, what we have now is as good a solution as it's possible to have.